# Are there any undergraduate research programs available online?

Tags: research-process, university, research-undergraduate, online-resource, online-learning

Is there something like an undergraduate research programme (given by a good institution) in mathematics/theoretical physics which provides a research opportunity in which I can collaborate online and leads to a publication?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any undergrad *research* program that provides courses, but that could just be terminology. Are you referring to a degree program, or a program that allows you to perform research while earning your degree elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise wording: I mean, a program (I would prefer it to be in english and held by a good institution) that allows me to do research and which suggests me some material to read and/or courses relevant for research (at undergrad level) while I'm earning my degree at my university.

Comment: Is your university not satisfied you? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Ooker there's nothing wrong, but in that university you've to be a PhD student in order to do some research, so I would like to know if there are other research opportunities

Comment: there is no program for researching in student level? Or some contests?

Comment: @Ooker unfortunately there isn't

Comment: And no contest from the city or your country? Cause in my opinion, in the level of student, research with no physical contact is not a good idea. Have you ask some of the PhD in your university to help you to start a project?

Comment: In the course catalog for your university, is there any type of "independent study" option. I.e., the sort of thing where you pick a topic and pursue it on your own, with some guidance from an instructor, and you earn course credits. Even if there isn't something like this in the catalog, perhaps the university would create it.

Comment: @mhwombat there is not

Comment: The organized undergrad research programs that I am familiar with (i.e. the US NSF's research experience for undergrads) are conceived in part as mentoring programs and the participants spend a lot of time with professors, grad students and post docs getting both formal instruction and simple exposure to the culture.

Comment: _there is not_ — I think it's time to transfer.

Comment: This question may help you: [Finding a research group where I can work remotely?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/finding-a-research-group-where-i-can-work-remotely)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check [The Open University](http://www.open.ac.uk/)'s site.

Under the [Studying for a Research Degree](http://mct-research.open.ac.uk/researchdegrees/home) section in the [Faculty of Mathematics, Computing and Technology](http://www9.open.ac.uk/mct/) site I found this:

> Part-time research students pursue their projects at a distance, under individual guidance from expert supervisors.

So maybe it is a possibility if you actually would like to earn a degree from that university, but since this institute is famous for the excellent quality online and distance education I think you should write them a message and ask for information. I guess they would have good suggestions about your question.

PS. I've taken an online course from this University on the [FutureLearn](https://www.futurelearn.com/) site, and the material's quality was very good.

Comment: The program you have referenced is *not* for undergraduate students. The "research degrees" there are at the M.S. and PhD level.